# post data to REST API using RESTClient for firefox addon

Tags: rest, post, firefox-addon

I am using RESTClient for firefox addon  to test REST API, i set some headers that's working fine if i set request body and method to GET , i couldn't access data via my PHP application, but headers available

```
**Request headers**   
   Content-Type : application/json

**Request Body**  

   [
   {
    "data1" : "value1",
    "data2" : "value2",
    "data3" : 1
    }
   ]
```

How do i set Request body correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a body to GET requests is a "nonsense" because GET means retrieve some information and the body of a request is used to send data.

It is precisely from this point of view that **web servers**, most of the time, **ignore the body of a GET request**, which could explain why you can't get your data from your PHP script.

If the purpose of your request is to **create** or **update** a resource you should consider using a **POST** or **PUT** to be REST.

There is already a topic opened with almost the same question here : [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)